# Tweet Analyis : How to design

Tags: java, multithreading, twitter4j

I need advice in designing a system meant for tweet analysis.

Objective: For a given hashtag, find out the frequency of co-occurrence with other hash-tags. Find out hourly pattern. We should be able to answer queries of this format: For a given date (say 13/Apr/2013) and for a given one hour time period (say 3:00-4:00 PM ) what are the top 5 co-occurring hashtag with "#iPhone".

My Approach: I am using "twitter4j" liabrary to access twitter data. I can query and get 100 tweets for one call(twitter only allows only those many). I can extract time and other relevant data. I am planning to have  thread which will query twitter for every 5 mins. This is done to observer hourly patterns. Here is where I am struck: How should I store this information in DB? Should I maintain a hashmap with key as  and value as frequency of occurring with "#iPhone". Or should I store unaggregated data directly in DB? what is the best way to query "twitter" to observer hourly patterns? Should I store the time in "epoch" format in DB or as date one column and hour as another column in DB ?

Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [the Streaming API in Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis). That will allow you to keep a persistent HTTP connection to twitter so that you can search over tweets. Twitter recommend the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public) for tweet analysis type applications.

But you have to pre-process certain data so that the analysis will be faster. Also look into [twitter4j's inherent Streaming API](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#streaming) support.

For an example please look into the following [Github code](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream/PrintSampleStream.java).

Answer (score 1):

As ay89 said, use key - tag and value - freq, aggregate before storing to DB, and use epoch.

In addition, because this is a multithreaded program, you have two options for synchronization:

Option 1 is to use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).  When the aggregator runs, it will use:

```
(for Key key : hashMap.keySet()) {
    Database.save(key, hashMap.get(key));
    hashMap.replace(key, 0);
}
```

In other words, set a tag's freq to 0 after writing it to the database.  And the method adding tweet data will use

```
public void increment(Key key) {
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done) {
        int current = hashMap.get(key);
        int newValue = current + 1;
        done = hashMap.replace(key, current, newValue);
    }
}
```

This is a thread-safe way to increment the frequency.

Option 2 probably makes more sense.  Your aggregator will replace the hashmap with a new instance.

```
class DataStore {
    Map map = new HashMap();

    public void add(Key key, Value value) {
        // called by the method querying tweet data
    }

    public void aggregate() {
       // called by the aggregator thread every five minutes
       Map oldMap = map;
       map = new HashMap();
       DataBase.save(oldMap);
   }
}
```

Bottom line is that you don't want to modify the hashmap in an uncontrolled fashion while the aggregator is saving it to the database.  The second option is simpler because it simply creates a new hashmap for the querying thread to modify while the aggregator saves the old hashmap to the database.

Answer (score 0):

since you only have to retrieve the frequency, its better to store it in hash, (key - tag, value - freq) because having non-aggregated data stored in db would take more space (and mostly for info which is not required) and ultimately you would have to aggregate it later.

epoch time is good way to store the time. since you can use it to localize it according to timezone, if required later on.